# How to execute multiple queries SQL Python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I'm trying to execute multiple queries. But it's executing the last one only knowing that I did `buffered=True` in the cursor. I need to get the result for the 4 queries.

```
updated_query = cursor.execute(
    'select count(*) from event where update_count > 0 and date > now() - interval 24 hour')
deleted_query = cursor.execute(
    'select count(*) from event where deleted > 0 and date > now() - interval 24 hour')
total_last_24_hours = cursor.execute(
    'select count(*) from event where date > now() - interval 24 hour')
total_events = cursor.execute('select count(*) from event')

result = cursor.fetchall()
for x in result:
    print(x[0])
```

Output: `3550` which is `total_events`

Comment: this is as expected. cursor.fetchall() is what fetches the results from the last query.

Comment: So how can I execute all the queries, Sir? @tomgalpin

Comment: Curious, why did you not use [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73621161/1422451) from your previous question?

Answer (score 1):

Since all four aggregate queries share same source table, consider combining all calculations in a single `SELECT` query. For long format, use the [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73621161/1422451) to your previous question.

```py
updated_query = (
    '''select sum(case
                     when update_count > 0 and date > now() - interval 24 hour
                     then 1
                     else 0
                  end) as update_count,
              sum(case
                     when deleted > 0 and date > now() - interval 24 hour
                     then 1
                     else 0
                  end) as delete_count,
              sum(case
                     when date > now() - interval 24 hour
                     then 1
                     else 0
                  end) as day_count,
              count(*) as total_count
        from event
    '''
)     

result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    print(row)
```